# JS Promises: is there a neat way to resolve multiple promises as object properties?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I wrote the below code then realised it was resolving early (logging before all promises resolve):

```
readDirPromise
.then(categoriseFiles)
.then(({movies, series}) => ({
  movies: Promise.all(movies.map(movieTasks)),
  series: Promise.all(series.map(seriesTasks))
}))
.then((res) => {
  console.log(' done!', res)
})
```

I've managed to rewrite it to resolve in the correct order:

```
readDirPromise
.then(categoriseFiles)
.then((cats) => Promise.all(cats.movies.map(movieTasks)).then((movies) => {
  cats.movies = movies
  return cats
}))
.then((cats) => Promise.all(cats.series.map(seriesTasks)).then((series) => {
  cats.series = series
  return cats
}))
.then((res) => {
  console.log(' done!', res)
})
```

but I can't help but think... is there a neater, more extensible way?

Comment: @Randy good point, updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the series step run independently of the movies step (rather than blocking one after the other) by wrapping both of them in another layer of `Promise.all`, coming back as a tuple which you may then destructure and restructure into the object you want:

```
readDirPromise
.then(categoriseFiles)
.then(({movies, series}) => Promise.all([
  Promise.all(movies.map(movieTasks)),
  Promise.all(series.map(seriesTasks))])
.then(([movies, series]) => ({movies, series}))
.then((res) => {
  console.log(' done!', res)
})
```

Comment: Great, this makes a lot of sense.. I keep forgetting you can destructure arrays like that, thanks!  I'll keep this open for a few days in case there are some other interesting solutions, but this seems to answer the question well.

Comment: you need to wrap `{movies, series}` and `[movies, series]` in parenthesis btw

Comment: Mm, true. Not sure where I picked up the notion somewhere in the midst of writing this answer that destructuring counted as a delimited argument list meaning no parentheses would be necessary. (Come to think of it, though, shouldn't it be?)

Comment: you missed a set on the restructuring. i've got in the habit of wrapping all arguments in parenthesis even if there's only one.. :)

Comment: D'oh! I was *just thinking about* comma-statements-within-brace-blocks after I made the edit (unlike destructuring before a fat arrow, this *would* be grammatically ambiguous without the parens) - should have recognized the flub.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I believe the async/await version of this would be something like:

```
async function generateResponse() {
  const {movies, series} = await readDirPromise.then(categoriseFiles);
  return {
    movies: await Promise.all(movies.map(movieTasks)),
    series: await Promise.all(series.map(seriesTasks))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of chaining the promises, you can create separate promises and resolve them in the the `Promise.all` method as you have done.

```
var p1 = getNewPromise();
var p2 = getNewPromise();
var p3 = getNewPromise();
```

// From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(values => { 
  console.log(values); 
});
```

Comment: Ahh.. I think I get your point - don't return an object with keys, but rather create promises as variables then return `Promise.all()` - however this changes the resolved data shape with no clear way to get it back again.. please elaborate.